# App Tracking Transparency privacy checkboxes and app store release rejection

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect, appstore-approval

I keep getting my iOS app submission rejected by apple with the following message:

> Guideline 5.1.2 - Legal - Privacy - Data Use and Sharing
>
> The app privacy information you provided in App Store Connect still
> indicates you collect data in order to track the user, including User
> ID and Product Interaction. However, you do not use App Tracking
> Transparency to request the user's permission before tracking their
> activity.
>
> Starting with iOS 14.5, apps on the App Store need to receive the
> user’s permission through the AppTrackingTransparency framework before
> collecting data used to track them. This requirement protects the
> privacy of App Store users.
>
> Next Steps
>
> Here are two ways to resolve this issue:
>
> - If you do not currently track, or decide to stop tracking, update your app privacy information in App Store Connect. You must have the
>   Account Holder or Admin role to update app privacy information.
> - If you track users, you must implement App Tracking Transparency and request permission before collecting data used to track. When you
>   resubmit, indicate in the Review Notes where the permission request is
>   located.
>
> Resources
>
> - Tracking is linking data collected from your app with third-party data for advertising purposes, or sharing the collected data with a
>   data broker. Learn more about tracking.
> - See Frequently Asked Questions about the new requirements for apps that track users.
> - Learn more about designing appropriate permission requests.

I already updated my app not to use any IDFA calls (including all the facebook and other SDKs) https://developer.apple.com/documentation/adsupport/asidentifiermanager/1614151-advertisingidentifier

When I try to set the checkboxes in App Privacy section of the app they can't be completely uncheck (i.e. at least one of the options has to be selected) so I can't state that my app is no using device id even though the codebase doesn't make advertisingidentifier at all.

[image: app store privacy checkboxes device id screenshot]

Does App Tracking Transparency really mean that we can't track anything, even user clicks on buttons and screen views???? If so that's insane!

The main issue is that I want to have a better user experience for my users by not showing them an unnecessary ATT prompt.

Comment: In the previous screen you have to uncheck "device id" if you don't use a device id at all. At the moment you have indicated that you are collecting a device id so you must indicate at least one reason you are collecting a device id. If your analytics is collecting a device id then tick the analytics box. If you associate the user id with your analytics then implement ATT as required.

Comment: @Paulw11 that's the problem, I cannot uncheck that box. If I uncheck all the boxes in device id prompt the "next" button is gray and can't be clicked!

Comment: No, not in the screen you have shown. In an earlier screen there was a checkbox for whether you use the device id *at all*. That is what you need to uncheck.

Comment: What are the swift and the objective-c tag for?  What difference does it make whether you write code in Swift or Objective-C in regard to the ATT violation?

Comment: @Paulw11 where do I find it? Is it the data types/data collection popup? I only see two options there - 1. we collect data, 2. we don't collect any data.

Comment: @ElTomato because this is relevant to anyone building iOS apps and Swift/Obj-C tag brings up visibility to those devs because predominantly people who are using both languages work on iOS apps.

Comment: After i answer "yes we collect data" I see a screen that asks what sort of data. One of the options is "device id".  If I select that then I see the screen you are showing next. If you have already been through the "wizard" you need to select "edit" beside the data types

Comment: @Paulw11 ah, this makes sense! thank you! I wasn't the one who went through the wizard originally and I didn't know you could select it there! Resubmitted to Apple. Will post here on whether it's successful or not.

Comment: What exactly classifies as "Device ID" in Apple legal terms? Generating a random UUID, storing it and sending it to a backend is considered a device id even if not obtained using Apple's official APIs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do the following 2 things:

1. Update the `Data Types` section to remove the `Device Id`. You can find it on the top of the privacy section, then hit `Edit`, navigate through till the last `Next`s and uncheck the `Device Id`
   [image]
2. Update the `User ID` and `Product Interaction` sections to uncheck - `No, we do not track the user`. You can find it at the end of the privacy section, then hit `Edit`, navigate through till the last`Next`s and uncheck the above-mentioned box.

[image]

Submit the app again for review.

Answer (score 0):

We were facing same issue when we removed Tracking from application and NSUserTrackingUsageDescription key from app.
Our app was already live on store with tracking enabled. In new version we faced this issue. When app was rejected we just replied them that we are not using this anymore in our application so we removed tracking authentication popup. We also told them that we were not able to update in App privacy because live version have tracking enabled.

After that reply they approved.

Sample Answer to apple when we removed from existing app:

"we have removed NSUserTrackingUsageDescription and tracking from this version, so we also removed Tracking Permission Popup from this version. We tried to remove it from App Privacy, but we could not change the Privacy data types in the Appstore connect because the current live version does use that permission. Please review our request and approve our application submission"